# How to sort ArrayList of classes

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I am trying to sort arrayList of classes which have a abstract type.

Here is my interface

```
public interface iSomeInterface {
    public int level();
}
```

There are couple of implementation of this interface which is different by their level implementations.

```
public class LevelOne implements iSomeInterface {
    @Override
    public int level() {return 1;}
}

public class LevelTwo implements iSomeInterface {
    @Override
    public int level() {return 2;}
}
public class LevelThree implements iSomeInterface {
    @Override
    public int level() {return 3;}
}
```

if I have couple of instances of these classes and passing them to the `Levels` class

```
ArrayList<iSomeInterface> someInterfaces = new ArrayList<iSomeInterface>();
        someInterfaces.add(new LevelOne());
        someInterfaces.add(new LevelTwo());
        someInterfaces.add(new LevelOne());
        someInterfaces.add(new LevelThree());
        someInterfaces.add(new LevelOne());
        Levels levels = new Levels(someInterfaces);
```

How can I sort these classed based on their level value.

```
public class Levels {
    private ArrayList<iSomeInterface> someInterfaces;

    public Levels(ArrayList<iSomeInterface> someInterfaces){

        this.someInterfaces = someInterfaces;
    }

    public ArrayList<iSomeInterface> sorting(){

        //some code to sorting instances

        return someInterfaces;
    }
}
```

Answer :
Thanks for your helps, The final answer :

```
public class someComparator implements Comparator<iSomeInterface> {
 @Override
  public int compare(iSomeInterface first, iSomeInterface second) {
    return first.level()<second.level()?-1:first.level()==second.level()?0:1;
  }
}

public ArrayList<iSomeInterface> sorting(){
  Collections.sort(someInterfaces,new someComparator());
  return someInterfaces;
}
```

Comment: Have a look at Comparator. A stack overflow discussion here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839137/

Comment: Thanks for guidance, the example is for one concrete class, I am sort of confused how can I extending it to multiple classes

Comment: The comparator can work on the common interface `iSomeInterface` like so  `Comparator<? extends iSomeInterface>`, may even just be able to do `Comparator<iSomeInterface>` - have a play and see what works for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution if you're using java 8.

```
public ArrayList<iSomeInterface> sorting(){

    Collections.sort(someInterfaces, (iSomeInterface  i1, iSomeInterface  i2) -> i1.getLevel() - i2.getLevel());

    return someInterfaces;
}
```

If you're working in something prior to that you can implement your own comparator...with an anonymous inner class to still make a 1-liner...

```
public ArrayList<iSomeInterface> sorting(){
    Collections.sort(interfaces, new Comparator<iSomeInterface>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(iSomeInterface i1, iSomeInterface i2) {
            return i1.getLevel() - i2.getLevel();
        }
    });
    return interfaces;
}
```

I assume you want to modify your member variable, but you can always duplicate your list first.

(Note Collections is java.util.Collections)

Comment: Thanks, I am getting error `can not resolve the method compareTo`

Comment: since the method is `int level()`, the `compare()` implementation should only be `i1.level() - i2.level();`

Comment: oops, didn't pay enough attention to the use of primitive in the example. Editing answer to fix