# How To implement Compare to method for custom object

Tags: java, comparable

In java i have an arrayList of my own(implemented)  i have a sort method so i need  'compareTo' method thats why i implemented Comparable and made the class abstract. But if i  use arraylist from main i have to implement compare to method .But I cant understand how i can implement this.( I have a restriction, for example if  i have a arraylist of 'order' class i cant implement comparable in  order class)

Arraylist

```
public abstract class ArrayList<T>  implements  Comparable
```

inside sort function

```
    Comparable left=(Comparable)L[i];
    Comparable right=(Comparable)R[j];
    for(int k=start;k<=end;k++)
    {
        if(left.compareTo(right)<=0)
        {
            array[k]=L[i];
            i++;
            left=(Comparable)L[i];

        }
```

From main

```
ArrayList<Order> order = new ArrayList<Order>() {
        @Override
        public int compareTo(Object o) {
            if(this)// but this main is not order class this is arraylist class
            return 0;
        }
    };
```

Comment: Check what @Loic M. said. Basically when you implement `Comparable` interface that means you want that particular object to be comparable with other object that's why you have to implement `compareTo(Object o)` method. What you really want is to compare elements so you should implement `Comparable` interface on the elements in the List

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why does your `ArrayList` implements `Comparable`?  Do you want to compare 2 lists? 
If you want to compare or order the elements of the list, the elements should be Comparable, but not the list itself.

You can also have a look to the following issue: [How to use Comparator in Java to sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839137/how-to-use-comparator-in-java-to-sort) 
You will then have to implement a `Comparator` for your class `Order` (not the interface `Comparable`)

Comment: OOps. i have made a great a mistake.Thanks a lot