# javafx line chart sorted data

Tags: java, sorting, javafx

I'm trying to sort data string on both axis but it doesn't work.
The code is below :

```
    //defining the axes
    final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
    final Axis<String> yAxis = new CategoryAxis();
    xAxis.setLabel("Day");
    yAxis.setLabel("Duration");
    //creating the chart
    LineChart<String, String> dataDiagram = new LineChart<String,String>(xAxis,yAxis);
    dataDiagram.setAnimated(false);

    dataDiagram.setTitle("Data");
    Iterator<String> i = this.choosenActivities.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()){
        String choosenActivity= i.next();
        Activity activity = this.activities.get(choosenActivity);
        //defining a series
        ObservableList<Data<String, String>> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList() ;
        Iterator<Entry<Day,Long>> is = activity.durationPerDay.entrySet().iterator();
        while (is.hasNext()){
            Entry<Day,Long> e= is.next();
            //populating the series with data
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
            Date date = new Date();
            date.setTime(e.getValue());
            data.add(new Data<String,String>(e.getKey().toString(), dateFormat.format(date)));

        }
        SortedList<Data<String, String>> sortedData = new SortedList<>(data, (data1, data2) -> 
        data1.getXValue().compareTo(data2.getXValue()));
        SortedList<Data<String, String>> sortedData2 = new SortedList<>(sortedData, (data1, data2) -> 
        data1.getYValue().compareTo(data2.getYValue()));
        dataDiagram .getData().add(new Series<>(activite.nom,sortedData2));
    }
```

Result is that xaxis is well sorted with the entries {2016/7/13 ; 2016/7/14 ; 2016/7/18 ; etc.} in this order, but yaxis gives {00:00:01 ; 00:00:23 ; 00:00:07}

I'm looking for another way of formatting time(datas are Long give by System.currentTimeMillis()) as numbers instead of strings, or a way of sorting string in my case. 
I have seen tickLabelFormatter but it only allows to provide a prefix and a suffix to the number, not to format it as a time.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you sort your time data *before* transforming them to a `String` ?
In this case you could use

```
Collections.sort(list);
```

for the sorting because the natural order of longs. 
If it's really necessary to transform you data to `String` before sorting, you could try to write an custom `Comparator` to do the job.

[How to use Comparator in Java to sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839137/how-to-use-comparator-in-java-to-sort)

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm trying it.