# Sorting list of object by their date

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, sorting

I want to sort a list of Booking objects which was retrieved from a database. I want to sort this list and save it to orderedList. I then want to create another list which stores the last 10 bookings and next 10 bookings from todays date.

How can I do this?

```
Date now = new Date();
    Session session = User.getSession();
    Transaction transaction = null;

    try {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();

        String hql = "FROM Booking";
        Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
        List<Booking> bookingList = query.list();
        List<Booking> orderedList;

        for(int i =0; i<bookingList.size();i++){

        }

        transaction.commit();
```

Comment: Why can't you sort on database itself and retrive?

Comment: *I then want to create another list which stores the last 10 bookings and next 10 bookings from todays date* stores where ? in object or database ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Comparator in Java to sort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839137/how-to-use-comparator-in-java-to-sort)

Comment: I want to sort the objects in the in bookingList and store it in the orderList above. I then want to create a new list storing the last 10 and next 10 bookings from todays date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort your result when retrieving from database itself

```
String hql = "FROM Booking ORDER BY column_name";
```

[**Sorting with Hibernate**](http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-sort)