# How to sorting List<Object[]> in java

Tags: java

May I know how can I sort a `List<Object[]>` and order by more than one element ?

below is my code:
I retrieve my result from database using below code

```
public List<Object[]> readyToPrint() {
Query query = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT 
    so_order_no,so_bo_suffix,shortname1,ETD......;
    List<Object[]> allObject = query.getResultList(); 
   return allObject;
```

}

As what I know I can only read the result using Object am I right ? So i think i don't have any specific class. Then if the result of element[X] meet certain condition, I want to edit the content of that element, and then only I resorting the result again.

Then i retrieve my result using below code:

```
`List<Object[]> allList = salesOrderFacade.readyToPrint();
readyToPrintResult = new ArrayList<>();

for (Object[] list : allList) {
    if (outgoingFacade.checkReadyToDelivery(list[0].toString(), list[1].toString())) {
        readyToPrintResult.add(list);
    } 
}
```

`I want to sort my`readyToPrintResult` list by element 2 and follow by element 3.

I tried the code below;

`Collections.sort(readyToPrintResult, new Comparator<Object[]>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Object[] lines1, Object[] lines2) {
             return lines1[2].xxxxx;
        }
    });`

but I stuck in the return part. I not able to use "compare" code.

Example: 
I have a List of result :

-Apple , 11-01-2017 , Y , N

-Bubble ,11-01-2017 , Y ,N

-Cat , 11-01-2017 , Y ,N

-Dora , 11-01-2017 , N ,Y

-Elephant,11-01-2017, N,Y

Then if Elephant meet some condition, I want to change the list of result of elephant to :

Elephant,11-01-2017, Y,N

Then I would like to sorting the whole list and my expected result is as below: 
-Apple , 11-01-2017 , Y , N

-Bubble ,11-01-2017 , Y ,N

-Cat , 11-01-2017 , Y ,N

-Elephant,11-01-2017, Y,N

-Dora , 11-01-2017 , N ,Y

Anyone can help?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the actual type of the elements of your arrays?

Comment: Your problem stems from the fact that having a `List<Object[]>` is not a good idea. You either want `List<List<Object>>` or, **much** better yet, `List<List<SomeSpecificClass>>`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Comparator in Java to sort](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839137/how-to-use-comparator-in-java-to-sort)

Comment: It is not clear what exactly the contents of your List are. It would be helpful if you gave us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the expected result of the sorting

Comment: in java `Object` class is evil, don't use it :). use generic instead : https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_generics.htm

Comment: Dear all..
Thanks for your comment and answer.. I have updated my question... 
I think my question is not clear enough.. Sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `ActualType` with any type you expect that is `Comparable` (I suppose it most likely would be `String`):

```
readyToPrintResult.sort((o1, o2) -> {
    int res = ((ActualType) o1[2]).compareTo((ActualType) o2[2]);
    return res != 0 ? res : ((ActualType) o1[3]).compareTo((ActualType) o2[3]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

By declaring the `Object` type in the `Comparator` declaration, you get two `Object` parameters to compare in the `compare()` method.

So, you can invoke only `Object` methods on them and besides `Object` doesn't implement the `Comparable` interface.
With the `Object` declared class, finally,you have not a lot of way to exploit it but a tricky use of the `toString()`.

Whereas the error :

> But I got stuck on the return part. I'm not able to use compare code

```
return lines1[2].xxxxx;
```

You have two ways :

- you work with more specific class than `Object[]`. For example : `Line[]` (as you name it in this way).

In this way, you may specify the `Line` type in the `Comparator` declaration :

```
Collections.sort(readyToPrintResult, new Comparator<Line[]>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Line[] lines1, Line[] lines2) {
        return lines1[2].getValue().compareTo(lines2[2].getValue());
    }
});
```

It is the finer solution.

- If you cannot work with a more specific class than `Object[]` because you manipulate objects with distinct(and not derived) classes , you could check the type of the two parameters and cast them in the `compare()` method.
  It is a really not advised way because you will have to perform a a lot of boiler plate code, casts and handling the cases when the two values doesn't rely on the same type.

Answer (score 0):

The int returned by the compare code is based on your parameters.

If the first one (lines1[2]) is less than your second parameter (lines2[2]) then your compare method should return a negative integer.

If lines1[2] is greater than lines2[2] you return a positive integer.

If lines1[2] and lines2[2] are the same you could return 0 (and quit comparing these objects) or as you want it compare lines1[3] against lines2[3]. Here you have to check again and then return a negative or positive number or 0.