# JAVA: How to sort list on the base of the field

Tags: java, sorting, date, time

I have the following list and I want to sort this whole list on the basis of the date how can I do this?

```
List<DevicePing> devicePing=Arrays.asList(
                new DevicePing(1L,2017-11-21 10:10:10.0),
                new DevicePing(2L,2017-11-21 10:00:00.0),
                new DevicePing(3L,2017-11-21 10:15:10.0),
                new DevicePing(4L,2017-11-21 09:30:10.0),
                new DevicePing(5L,2017-11-21 09:45:10.0),
                new DevicePing(6L,2017-11-21 09:50:10.0),
                new DevicePing(7L,2017-11-21 09:55:10.0);
```

When I am using the following code it gives me an nullPointerException at o1.getDateTime()

```
Collections.sort(myList, new Comparator<MyObject>() {
  public int compare(MyObject o1, MyObject o2) {
      return o1.getDateTime().compareTo(o2.getDateTime());
  }
});
```

**EDITED**

Now I am using the following code but it print the same data instaed of sorted data

```
public void calculateTimesheet(RiderLocation riderLocation,List<DevicePing> devicePing,List<RiderAvailability> riderAvailability)
    {
        devicePing.sort(Comparator.comparing(DevicePing::getDate));
        for(DevicePing dp:devicePing)
        {
            System.out.println("dp: " + dp);
        }
    }
```

**DevicePing.java**

```
@Entity
public class DevicePing {

    public DevicePing(Long id ,Date createdAt) {
        this.id = id;
        this.createdAt = createdAt;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private User rider;

    @Column( nullable = false,columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date date;

    //getter nad setter
    }
```

Comment: Sort it from oldest to newest?

Comment: newest to oldest

Comment: Use a Comparator - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839137/how-to-use-comparator-in-java-to-sort

Comment: Also you're not showing the complete code. Please read upon [mcve]

Comment: try to use a LocalDateTime with the same code .

Comment: As an aside, in particular since you can use Java 8, I suggest you skip the long outdated `Date` class and instead use a class from `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API, for example `Instant` or `LocalDateTime` (the choice depending on your more exact requirements).

Comment: For your `NullPointerException`, could your list contain a `null`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try sorting it using:

`devicePing.sort(Comparator.comparing(DevicePing::getDateTime));`

Comment: `public void calculateTimesheet(RiderLocation riderLocation,List<DevicePing> devicePing,List<RiderAvailability> riderAvailability)
 {
  devicePing.sort(Comparator.comparing(DevicePing::getDate));
  for(DevicePing dp:devicePing)
  {
   System.out.println("dp: " + dp);
  }
 }`

I am tried your example but it prints the same data not sorted data

Comment: `DevicePing::getDateTime`, All your dates are on the same day. Use the Date and time

Comment: Actually it is a time stamp please check my edited question

Comment: What is the Java type? `LocalDateTime`? `Date`?

Comment: And I want to sort my list on the basis of the timestamp

Comment: Java type is Date

Comment: It works fine now.. Sorry it was my mistake , Thankyou so much God bless you

Comment: No problem, glad I could help :)