# Corting a two-dimensional array and copying strings

Tags: java, arrays, future

I wrote code that fills a two-dimensional array with data from a file.

```
 public static Collection getBrowser() {   
        return Arrays.asList(readFromFile("arr.txt"));
    }
    private static Object[][] readFromFile(String filePath) {
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));
            StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
            while (reader.ready()) {
                string.append(reader.readLine());
                string.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            }
            reader.close();
            String[] lineSplit = string.toString().split(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            Object[][] result = new Object[lineSplit.length][];
            for (int i = 0; i < lineSplit.length; i++) {
                String line = lineSplit[i];
                String[] itemSplit = line.split(",");
                result[i] = new Object[itemSplit.length];
                for (int j = 0; j < itemSplit.length; j++) {
                    if (j == 0) {
                        result[i][j] = Integer.valueOf(itemSplit[j]);
                    } else {
                        result[i][j] = itemSplit[j];
                    }
                  System.out.print(result[i][j]+" ");
                }
            //System.out.println();
            }
            return result;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Example file

```
 1000, a, a, x
    1000, x, x, y
    1200, c, c, y
```

Tell me please, how can I sort this array by the last value, by sweeping each line into a separate array

```
Arr1
1000, a, a, x
Arr2
1000, x, x, y
1200, c, c, y
```

Comment: What you want to achieve? How many values are possible in last column?

Comment: You need to tackle one problem at a time. Build the program up a little at a time. Start with hard-coded examples before reading from files: e.g. Do you want to start with something like this`String[][] data = { {"1000", "a", "a", "x"}, {"1200", "c", "c", "y"} };`

Comment: @Betlista, in the last column there can be 2 different values. On them I have to filter the rows

Comment: @DJDaveMark    Unfortunately, 1 value in the string must be int

Comment: When you read from a file, you're gonna have strings. If you can create a simpler example with hard-coded values, and show us a result you want (a hard-coded java variable), it'll be easier to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far you are on a good direction, so you are able to read a file... What you want to do next?

To me it doesn't really looks like 2D array, but more like array of Objects. Define object to wrap your data and the use [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

Once you'll implement Comparator, you can call `Arrays.sort(array, comparator)`.

See some help here: [How to use Comparator in Java to sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839137/how-to-use-comparator-in-java-to-sort)

You do not need to split to two arrays and sort separately, once you are more familiar with comparator, you can do that in one go...

Comment: thanks for the help. I have written an autotest that takes parameters from a file. But when all these parameters are in the same array, it does not follow the order. So I want to make 3 data arrays.