# Array to move the numbers in the starting and the special character at the last in array using java

Tags: java, arrays

I am having an array

int arr[]={1,$,2,3,$,$,4,5}

and want the output as

arr[]={1,2,3,4,5,$,$,$}

Can you please help me

My code is

```
public class ArrayTest
{
    static void splitString(String str)
    {
        StringBuffer alpha = new StringBuffer(), 
        num = new StringBuffer(), special = new StringBuffer();

        for (int i=0; i<str.length(); i++)
        {
            if (Character.isDigit(str.charAt(i)))
                num.append(str.charAt(i));

            else
                special.append(str.charAt(i));
        }


        System.out.print(num);
        System.out.print(special);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String str = "1,2,$,$,3,4";
        splitString(str);
    }
}
```

I am getting the O/P as 1234,,$,$,,
instead of 1,2,3,4,$,$

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: And what exactly is `$`?

Comment: I am unable to move the special character from there original place

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Comparator in Java to sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839137/how-to-use-comparator-in-java-to-sort)

Answer (score 0):

Sorting is not single activity. Sorting is actually ordering, and comparing.

You can use Java built-in sorting but your own comparator (piece of code that knows how to compare).

Your comparator, need to make sure that special sign is just bigger then any other value (and is equal to any other special sign). If neither compared value is special sign, do ordinary comparison.

Here is link to other question that explains how to do that:
[How to use Comparator in Java to sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839137/how-to-use-comparator-in-java-to-sort)

Answer (score 0):

From your output I can see that your function includes the commas in the sorting as well. You must remove the commas before sorting the String:

```
 str = str.replaceAll(",", "");
```

This line of code will replace all commas with nothing, or in other words remove them. Now you can execupe your sorting algorithm and add the commas at the end:

```
String merge = num.toString() + special.toString();
String result = "";
for (int i = 0; i < merge.length(); ++i) {
    result += merge.charAt(i) + ",";
}
```

This will put an additional comma at the end which you can remove very easily:

```
result = result.substring(0, result.length() - 1);
```

Now `result` holds the wanted result.