# Sorting strings in a list based on indexes

Tags: java, string, sorting, arraylist

If i have an `ArrayList` of strings 
`["bb", "ab", "cf", "aa"]` how can I sort alphabetically by the 1st or nth index and onward (if 1st index is the same character for other strings) ?  Is there a method I can use to do so?

The list above, I would expect for index = 1

`["aa", "bb", "ab", "cf"]`

Another example would

`["bab", "baa", "abbe", "cff"]` would return

`["baa", "bab", "abbe", "cff"]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Comparator in Java to sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839137/how-to-use-comparator-in-java-to-sort) (p.s. not the downvoter)

Comment: it is not correct java strings

Comment: By using a comparator that extracts the nth character of both strings and compares them. Try something at least.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Comparator.comparingInt` to perform this sort:

Using index `0` to sort arrays:

```
String[] s = {"bb", "ab", "cf", "aa"};
Arrays.sort(s, Comparator.comparingInt(s1 -> s1.charAt(0)));
Arrays.asList(s).forEach(System.out::println);
```

or sort lists:

```
List<String> s = Arrays.asList("bb", "ab", "cf", "aa");
s.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(s2 -> s2.charAt(0)));
s.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Outputs:

> ```
> ab
> aa
> bb
> cf
> ```

Otherwise using index `1` for sort arrays:

```
String[] s = {"bb", "ab", "cf", "aa"};
Arrays.sort(s, Comparator.comparingInt(s2 -> s2.charAt(1)));
Arrays.asList(s).forEach(System.out::println);
```

or index 1 for sorting lists

```
List<String> s = Arrays.asList("bb", "ab", "cf", "aa");  
s.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(s2 -> s2.charAt(1)));
s.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Outputs:

> ```
> aa
> bb
> ab
> cf
> ```

PS: You question about `java`, but your `strings` and `array` like `javascript`..

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this simple example:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> listOfStrings = new LinkedList<>();
        listOfStrings.add("aa");
        listOfStrings.add("bb");
        listOfStrings.add("ge");
        listOfStrings.add("be");
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(listOfStrings));
        String getMe = listOfStrings.remove(3);
        listOfStrings.add(0, getMe);
        System.out.println(Arrays.asList(listOfStrings));
    }
```

`LinkedList` are good for insterting and removing elements and this can be done in `O(1)` (change it locally ), also I would like to mention that adding or removing a head of the list is done in `O(1)` too which is optimal for your cause.