# How can I assign data from a file to an array

Tags: java

I have a file, which looks like follows:

Barack Obama        3
Michael Jackson     1
Dua Lipa            2
...          all of 15 lines

I need to read from a file and place names in a one-dimensional array and integers into another, then sort everything from smallest int to biggest.

I was looking for help everywhere, I tried to google it and looked through many articles. I couldn't find the answer. That's what I tried but I know it's wrong.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Boombastic {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\bobo\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\" + "boombastic\\boombastic.txt");

        String[] fullName;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            fullName[] = sc.next();
        }
    }
}
```

Could you please help me to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

Use `scanner.nextLine()`.
Also, I recommend using ArrayList because you don't know how many lines scanner has. If you do, then you can keep using arrays.

Using ArrayList:

```
public class Boombastic {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\bobo\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\" + "boombastic\\boombastic.txt");

        ArrayList<String> fullName = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
        Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(file); // For the integers.

        while(sc.hasNext()) {
            fullName.add(sc.nextLine());
            ints.add(sc2.nextInt());
        }
    }
}
```

Using arrays (assuming the scanner has 3 lines):

```
public class Boombastic {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\bobo\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\" + "boombastic\\boombastic.txt");

        String[] fullName = new String[3];
        int[] ints = new int[3];
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
        Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(file);
        int i = 0;
        while (sc.hasNext()) {
            fullName[i ++] = sc.next();
            ints[i ++] = sc2.nextInt();
        }
}
```

}

And to sort it, do

```
Arrays.sort(fullName);
Arrays.sort(ints);
```

This isn't the most efficient method, since it uses two scanners, but it works.

Comment: Thank you for your help. When I try to run, it says:
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2117)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2076)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to assign the data to an array using separators and stuff, it is better to read all lines in a `String` and then process this `String`. There are plenty ways of how to read the lines of a text file into a `String`. Some basic of them can be found in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4716503/reading-a-plain-text-file-in-java).

However, I would not split the data and "store" them into Arrays since you do not know how much your data is. Also, I would choose "a more object oriented programming way" to achieve it. I would create a class, and objects of it will represent this data. After that I'd add these objects to collection and use Java's APIs to sort it within one line.

Finally, instead of `new File("C:\\Users\\bobo\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\" + "boombastic\\boombastic.txt");` use `File` class constructor to build the path. Messing with separators  is yikes...

An example would be:

```
public class Boombastic {
    public static class Person {
        private String firstName, lastName;
        private int id; // ??

        public Person(String firstName, String lastName, int id) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
            this.lastName = lastName;
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getFirstName() {
            return firstName;
        }

        public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
            this.firstName = firstName;
        }

        public String getLastName() {
            return lastName;
        }

        public void setLastName(String lastName) {
            this.lastName = lastName;
        }

        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Person [firstName=" + firstName + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", id=" + id + "]";
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File desktop = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"), "Desktop");
        File textFileWithData = new File(desktop, "data.txt");
        List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();

        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(textFileWithData))) {
            String line = br.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                String[] lineSplit = line.split("\\s");
                Person person = new Person(lineSplit[0], lineSplit[1], Integer.parseInt(lineSplit[2]));
                persons.add(person);
                line = br.readLine();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("File cannot be read.");
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(0);
        }
        // print unsorted
        persons.forEach(System.out::println);
        Collections.sort(persons, (p1, p2) -> p1.getId() - p2.getId()); // Sort persons by ID
        System.out.println();
        // print sorted
        persons.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

If you are having hard time to understand the sort part, take a look at [how to use comparator in java.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839137/how-to-use-comparator-in-java-to-sort)

My text file:

```
John Doe 3
Someone Else 2
Brad Pitt 5
Kevin Spacey 1
```

Output:

```
Person [firstName=John, lastName=Doe, id=3]
Person [firstName=Someone, lastName=Else, id=2]
Person [firstName=Brad, lastName=Pitt, id=5]
Person [firstName=Kevin, lastName=Spacey, id=1]

Person [firstName=Kevin, lastName=Spacey, id=1]
Person [firstName=Someone, lastName=Else, id=2]
Person [firstName=John, lastName=Doe, id=3]
Person [firstName=Brad, lastName=Pitt, id=5]
```