# How to sort data with selection sort?

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors, selection-sort

I am trying to sort the data in the array.
I have already created a method that sorts the data but for some reason, I can not call this method correctly in the `main` method.

Something doesn't work. The `driver` class has to call up the method and send in the correct parameters. I tried to do so but it doesn't work. Something is wrong with the parameters. This program is supposed to receive data and sort it.

```
public class Kennel
    {
        public static <T extends Comparable<T>>
                  void selSort(T[] doggy)
        {
            //local variables
            T temp;
            Dog doggy[ ] = new Dog [MAX_DOGS];       //dog array
            int outerLoop;         //  Outer loop counter
            int innerLoop;         //Inner loop counter
            int location;          //Location of smallest value
            int n = doggy.length;                 //number of items in the array
        
            /***************************************************/
        
            
            for (outerLoop = 0; outerLoop < n - 1; outerLoop++)
            {
                //
                location = outerLoop;
        
                //
                for (innerLoop = outerLoop + 1; innerLoop < n; innerLoop++)
                {
                    if (doggy[location].compareTo((doggy[innerLoop])) > 0)
                    {
                       location = innerLoop;
        
                    }//end IF
        
                }//end FOR
        
                >swap the value of the old smallest with the value of the new smallest<
                T iSwap = doggy[location];
                doggy[location] = doggy[outerLoop];
                doggy[outerLoop] = iSwap;
        
            }//end FOR
        
        }//end selSort
```

**main method**

```
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        mid = new Kennel();
        mid.selSort(mid.doggy);
    }
```

When I compile the code I get an error:

```
 117: error: method selSort in class Kennel cannot be applied to given types;
                mid.selSort(mid.doggy);
                   ^
   required: T[]
   found: Dog[]
   reason: inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)
     inferred: Dog
     upper bound(s): Comparable<Dog>
   where T is a type-variable:
     T extends Comparable<T> declared in method <T>selSort(T[])
 1 error
```

Not sure how to fix this problem.

Comment: `Dog` must actually implement `Comparable<Dog>` for your code to work.

Comment: public static <T extends Comparable<Dog>>
           void selSort(T[] doggy)

Comment: That doesn't seem right. It send me an error

Comment: The class `Dog` (which you did not post). The one you have with `Dog doggy[ ] = new Dog [MAX_DOGS];` - **that `Dog`**.

Answer (score 1):

A couple points.

- your Dog class should look something like

```
class Dog implements Comparable<Dog> {
  // fields, constructor, etc here

  public int compareTo(Dog dog) {
     ...
     return val; // where val is an int depending on result of comparison
  }
  // other methods here.
}
```

- It makes no sense to have a `Dog array` in the sort method and also accept one as an argument.  The Dog array will be sorted in place so no internal array of dogs is required.
- You need to populate a `Dog array` with `Dog objects` and pass that array to the sort method.

Also check [how-to-use-comparator-in-java-to-sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839137/how-to-use-comparator-in-java-to-sort)

Comment: Thanks, I am a little confused about compareTo method. Could you please give explain more?

Comment: @James `Comparable` and `compareTo` have been covered many many times already on Stack Overflow. Search to learn more. And study the Java Tutorials provided free-of-cost by Oracle.

Comment: @BasilBourque yeah u right. Im sorry im dumb lol