# Using Comparator to sort ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, lambda, comparator

I have been working on a Scrabble assignment. I need to read words from a list, then read each char and assign a value, eventually assigning a total score to each word. That has been done! Phew. Now I need to use the Comparator to sort the words from greatest score to least. I have done a lot of reading and I'm still confused. I know that I could use the interface, but there's also using Comparator with a lambda expression, which is the direction that I think I want to go. I'm just not sure how. I need to compare the sumValue I have for each word, then print the words in decreasing order.

I created 2 loops to read the word (i), then the chars (j). I have printed to the screen the score of each word (sumValue) and its location (i) in my ArrayList. Now I need to use Comparator to compare the scores, and then reorder the location. I think my problem is that I feel like I'm not sorting the Arraylist. I'm sorting the scores, which are not in an ArrayList. Do I need to create a new ArrayList with scores attached to each word and sort that?

Comment: What programming language are your working with?

Comment: Could you share an example

Comment: If you're working in Java, this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839137/how-to-use-comparator-in-java-to-sort

Comment: I'm working in Java. I added a couple of pics of what I have so far, with the middle cut out as all the if statements don't need to be shown. I am a beginning student. My code is cumbersome, I know. But I'm pretty proud of what I was able to do on my own. Just need guidance on how to use Comparator correctly.

Comment: [Don't post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: Please post the actual code and not images.

Comment: I have removed the pictures. I apologize. I am new to posting here and didn't realize this was an issue. I don't want to copy my code as I am in a programming class and working on assignments. I am trying to be vague enough that I get pointed in the right direction without anyone giving me coded answers as that is not what I'm looking for. I will try to figure out better ways to ask my questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like so. The `List` interface has a `sort()` method that takes a
[`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html).

The common practice for defining a Comparator is to make use of one of its static methods, like [`Comparator.comparing(Function<? super T,? extends U> keyExtractor)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing(java.util.function.Function)).
In this case, the `KeyExtractor` would be the `Word.getValue` method
specified as a method reference (a lambda would also work).

But first, you should create a `record` or `class` to hold the word and value. That is so when you sort the records based on the value, the word and value will still be together as a unit.

```
record Word(String getWord, int getValue) {
     @Override
     public String toString() {
         return "%s -> %d".formatted(getWord, getValue);
     }
}
```

Here I have created a list of `Word` records.  The values are arbitrary for demonstration.

```
List<Word> list = new ArrayList<>(
       List.of(new Word("the", 30), new Word("Hello", 20), new Word("GoodBye", 2)));

list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Word::getValue));
System.out.println(list);
```

prints

```
[GoodBye -> 2, Hello -> 20, the -> 30]
```

You can also sort in reverse order.

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparing(Word::getValue).reversed());
System.out.println(list);
```

prints

```
[GoodBye -> 2, Hello -> 20, the -> 30]
```

I would also suggest using a Map to hold the letters and their point value.

```
Map<String, Integer> letterMap = Map.of("A",1,"B",1,"C",1, ....);
```

Then you can access them like this.

```
int point = letterMap.get("A");
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have a score calculating method:

```
int score(String word) {
    ...
}
```

And a list of words:

```
Path path = Paths.get("C:/words.txt");
List<String> words = Files.readAllLines(path, Charset.defaultCharset());

words.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(this::score)
                     .thenComparing(Function.identity()));
```

This will first sort on the score, and then alphabetically for the same score.

The comparing/comparingInt/ComparingDouble/... functions indicate the function that will give one comparison key (from the word).
For the comparison of the words them selve `Function.identity()` will use the word itself.