# Find duplicates in List by 2 level deep property

Tags: java, list, filtering, distinct-values

I'm not sure what to call the property that's 2 layers deep.

But let's say we have `List<FruitColor>` where `Fruit` and `Color` are 2 entities. (These are all example entities) A `fruit` can have different `color`s, but `color`s can also have different `fruit`s.

```
public class FruitColor {
    private String fruitColorId;
    private Fruit fruit;
    private Color color;
    private int ripe; //1 to 3 where 1 unripe 2 normal 3 ripe

    // more props, getters, etc.
}

public class Fruit {
    private String fruitId;
    private String fruitName;

    // getters, etc.
}

public class Color {
    private String colorId;
    private String colorName;

    // getters, etc.
}
```

I'm thinking it in the following steps:

1. Filter all the duplicates by `fruitName`
2. Pick one of the two 'duplicates'. I say 'duplicates' because they only have the same `name`, but not the same `color`. The rule to choose which one to keep is the season/time-transition indicator `systemTransition`, which is described by the `double` property `systemTransition` that ranges from `0` to a `100`.
3. Remove the other 'duplicate'.
4. If there is a duplicate, makes the fruit less ripe by `0.5`
5. Set the `factorialRipeness`, which is `ripe * systemTransition`
   or `ripe * (100 - systemTransition)` depending on how far we are in the season, halfway is the threshold.
6. Return suggested `FruitColors` with the right `Color`, sorted by `FactorialRipeness`
   The thing is, this is probably do-able with a lot of for loops, but I'm just wondering if there are any ways that are more efficient.

I did find this source on how to filter by property, but this solution doesn't let me filter on the property of a property(=`fruitName`).
[Java 8 Distinct by property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23699371/java-8-distinct-by-property)

I've made a code example (again different entities) that works. Are there any parts that could be made more efficient? By more efficient I mean, if the code could be shorter and/or faster. I'll definitely refactor the method into smaller parts later. Sorry for the confusing bits, this problem is really hard to explain without using the exact same entities.

```
//logic in the method
{   
    List<FruitColor> fruitColors = getAllFCs();
    
    //Remove if FC is neither colors that were chosen
    fruitColors.removeIf(fc -> fc.getColor().getColorId() != presentColor.getColor().getColorId()
            && fc.getColor().getColorId() != futureColor.getColor().getColorId());
    List<FruitColor> suggestedFruits = new ArrayList<>();

    //Systemtransition is the season/time from 0 to 100, where 100 the fruit should be completely ripe with the corresponding color.
    //If the time is less than half, it should pick the present color, which is the less ripe color.
    boolean getPresentColorFruit = systemTransition < 50;

    // --->This whole for-if-if-else-elseif-if-else part I wanted to make more "efficient" <---
    for (FruitColor fruitColor : fruitColors) {
        //First check for duplicate FCs 
        List<FruitColor> sameNameFruits = fruitColors.stream()
                .filter(fc -> fc.getFruit().getName().equals(itemColor.getFruit().getName()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
                
        //If there is only one of the fruit, check if it's added already. If not, than add with proper ripeness
        //FactorialRipeness is the "true" ripeness.
        if (sameNameFruits.size() == 1 && !suggestedFruits.stream().anyMatch(fc -> fc.getFruit().getName().equals(sameNameFruits.get(0).getFruit().getName()))) {
            FruitColor onlyOne = sameNameFruits.get(0);
            if (onlyOne.getColor().getColorId() == presentColor.getColor().getColorId()) {
                onlyOne.setFactorialRipeness(onlyOne.getRipeness() * systemTransition);
            } else {
                onlyOne.setFactorialRipeness(onlyOne.getRipeness() * (100 - systemTransition));
            }
            suggestedFruits.add(onlyOne);
          // If there are multiple FCs, than the ripeness has to go down. Which prioritizes duplicate FCs more. (this part isn't logical with these entities, sorry)
        } else if(!suggestedFruits.stream().anyMatch(fc -> fc.getFruit().getName().equals(sameNameFruits.get(0).getFruit().getName()))){
            if (getPresentColorFruit) {
                FruitColor fcWithPresentColor = sameNameFruits.stream()
                        .filter(fc -> fc.getColor().getColorId() == presentColor.getColor().getColorId()).findFirst()
                        .get();
                fcWithPresentColor.setFactorialRipeness((fcWithPresentColor.getRipeness() - 0.5) * systemTransition);
                suggestedFruits.add(fcWithPresentColor);
            } else {
                FruitColor fcWithFutureColor = sameNameFruits.stream()
                        .filter(fc -> fc.getColor().getColorId() == futureColor.getColor().getColorId()).findFirst()
                        .get();
                //This part is also not logical, but if the presentColor is not chosen. Than we need to multiply by the opposite amount of the systemTransition
                fcWithFutureColor.setFactorialRipeness((fcWithFutureColor.getRipeness() - 0.5) * (100 - systemTransition)); 
                suggestedFruits.add(fcWithFutureColor);
            }
        }
    }
    //Sort by "true" ripeness value, from lowest to highest
    Collections.sort(suggestedFruits, new FruitColorRipenessComparator());
    return suggestedFruits;
}

/**
 * @source https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2839137/how-to-use-comparator-in-java-to-sort
 */
public class FruitColorRipenessComparator implements Comparator<FruitColor> {
    @Override
    public int compare(FruitColor a, FruitColor b){
        return a.getFactorialRipeness() < b.getFactorialRipeness() ? -1 : a.getFactorialRipeness() == b.getFactorialRipeness() ? 0 : 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, okay I'll start making a version with loops and clarify it with that as example. Also the rule to choose which one to keep is how ripe the fruit is, from 0 to a 100, which was  a property in `fruit` that I didn't include. @AlexanderIvanchenko

Answer (score 1):

As a possible option you can group `FruitColor` instances by the `name` property of their `fruit`s by storing them into a `Map`. And then dump the values into a list.

It can be implemented with Stream API using Collector [`toMap(keyMapper,valueMapper,mergeFunction)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator)).

> the rule to choose which one to keep is how ripe the fruit is, from 0 to a 100, which was a property in fruit

To implement the `mergeFunction`, which is meant to resolve values mapped to the same key we can use static method [`BinaryOpearator.maxBy()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/BinaryOperator.html#maxBy(java.util.Comparator)), which expects a `Comparator`.

Comparator that compares `FruitColor` instances based `rape` property of the `fruit` field might be expressed in the following way:

```
Comparator.comparingInt(fruitColor -> fruitColor.getFruit().getRipe())
```

or alternatively as:

```
Comparator.comparing(
    FruitColor::getFruit,
    Comparator.comparingInt(Fruit::getRipe)
)
```

That's the overall implementation might look like:

```
List<FruitColor> fruitColors = // initializing the list
        
List<FruitColor> fruitColorsDistinct = fruitColors.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        fruitColor -> fruitColor.getFruit().getFruitName(), // keyMapper
        Function.identity(),  // valueMapper
        BinaryOperator.maxBy( // mergeFunction - resolving duplicates
            Comparator.comparingInt(fruitColor -> fruitColor.getFruit().getRipe())
        )
    ))
    .values().stream()
    .toList();
```