# Order an ArrayList of Set of String

Tags: java, arraylist, set

I have an ArrayList of Set of String in Java

```
List<Set< String >> combinations;
```

What is the best way to order the ArrayList based on the size of the Set in an ascending order?

Comment: Ascending order of *what*??

Comment: Ascending order of what? Which should come first: {A, D} or {B, C}?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477261/how-to-sort-a-collectiont/

Answer (score 4):

Write a `Comparator<Set<String>>` that compares the `size()` results from the two Set instances. Use the Collections.sort method that takes a Comparator as the second argument.