# Sorting a list of objects in Java according to booleans

Tags: java

I have this class:

```
public class Turn {

public boolean turnMoved;
public int moveSelectionX;
public int moveSelectionY;
public int moveTargetX;
public int moveTargetY;

public boolean turnFired;
public int shotSelectionX;
public int shotSelectionY;
public int shotTargetX;
public int shotTargetY;

//Set this to true when doing a turn if we fired before moving
//Else if we do move/shot in the wrong order, we might select an empty cell
boolean firedFirst = false;
}
```

Elsewhere in my program, I create a list of these objects. Once the list is completed, I'd like to sort the list in this order, so that all the objects that satisfy 1. will be at the front of the list, and so on:

1. turnMoved && turnFired == true
2. turnFired == true
3. turnMoved == true
4. turnMoved && turnFired == false

What would the easiest way to do this be?

Comment: What have you tried? There must be thousands of examples on the web that show how to sort a list of objects in Java.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to sort a Collection<T>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477261/how-to-sort-a-collectiont)

Comment: Have you looked in to the Comparable interface? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

Comment: I've tried implementing comparable, but when I use CompareTo I get an error because I'm using booleans.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have your class implement `Comparable<Turn>`, write a `compareTo` that reflects your preferences, and use `Collections.sort` to sort the list.

Comment: I was having some problems before with an error when using compareTo with booleans.

Would something like this be on the right lines for the first part? I don't have the code to hand at the moment so can't test it.

    public int compareTo(Turn t1) {
            if (this.turnMoved == t1.turnMoved)
                return 0;
            else if (this.turnMoved > t1.turnMoved)
                return 1;
            else
                return -1;
        }

Comment: You can't use `>` in reference to `boolean`s, so no, it probably wouldn't be like that. :)

Comment: if (this.turnMoved == true && t1.turnMoved == false) return 1, then?

Comment: In general, if you want `this` to appear in the list before `t1`, then you should return `1`. Conversely, if you want `t1` to appear before `this`, then you should return `-1`.