# Duel Masters game in Java

Tags: java

I was trying to make a [Duel Masters card game](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duel_Masters_Trading_Card_Game) in Java using BlueJ, and came up with a lot of ideas. However, I could not exactly figure out how to sort a deck on basis of the card names in the game.
I have an array of Card objects(each has, as its instance variables: String name, int cost, int civ), and I want to sort them based on name. ie: if I have the cards "Pyrofighter Magnus", "Bazagazeal Dragon" and another "Pyrofighter Magnus" in the array, the cards should be sorted on basis of their names.

I know that I could use `compareTo()`, but is there an easier method? Anyone?

Comment: `"I know that I could use compareTo(), but is there an easier method?"` -- Making your Card class implement `Comparable<Card>` and using `compareTo(...)` **is** an easy way to do this. Why throw this out, out of hand? `"Remember, the method that sorts the cards should be a modifier."` -- this statement doesn't make sense to me. Please clarify.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to sort a Collection<T>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477261/how-to-sort-a-collectiont)

Comment: All right, I'll try it.

Comment: Whether you wish to sort them alphabetically or by taxonomical grouping, I believe your answer would lie in the javadoc for strings (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Comment: @Hovercraft: The compiler throws up an error saying that classes Card, Creature and Spell(Creature and Spell extend Card) need to be abstract to implement Comparable. I made them abstract, but now I get a new error: "Creature is an abstract class and cannot be instantiated". Basically, the compiler isn't letting me create instances of my Cards!

Comment: Arun, you're fixing the wrong thing. Don't make them abstract! Give them the necessary methods. And you may need to have it implement `Comparable<? extends Card>` or something similar, but keep at it, since this is the correct way to do this.

Comment: Good, and ignore what I stated about `Comparable<? extends Card>` as that's wrong.

Comment: I know this is a bit off-topic, but I think you'll fare much better if you switch to some other IDE like NetBeans or Eclipse. Once you become more confident in Java, BlueJ might be a little restricting.