# grouping similar strings from a csv file and find the number of occurences

Tags: java, csv, guava

i need to group CSV columns such that

```
User ID       Group
ABC           Group1   
DEF           Group2
ABC           Group3
GHI           Group4
XYZ           Group2
UVW           Group5
XYZ           Group1
ABC           Group1
DEF           Group2
```

Output should be such that

```
ABC   Group1 ->2
ABC   Group3 ->1
DEF   Group2 ->2
GHI   Group4 ->1
UVW   Group5 ->1
XYZ   Group2 ->1
XYZ   Group1 ->1
```

and need to group the data such that for ex. in ABC-->((group1 occurs twice)/(total number of occurences of ABC))+((group3 occurs once)/(total number of occurences of ABC)). so ABC-->2/3+1/3

```
ABC--> 2/3(no. of occurences of ABC)+1/3
DEF-->2/2
GHI-->1/1
UVW-->1/1
XYZ-->1/2+1/2
```

the first set of results is got using GUAVA lib

```
Multiset<String> set = TreeMultiset.create();        
    BufferedReader reader = null;        
    try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.csv"));            
        String[] currLineSplitted;            
        while (reader.ready()) {
            currLineSplitted = reader.readLine().split(",");
            set.add(currLineSplitted[0] + "," + currLineSplitted[1]);                
        }            
        for (String key : set.elementSet()) {            
            System.out.println(key + " : " + set.count(key));
        }            
    } finally {
        if (reader != null) {
            reader.close();
        }
    }
```

not sure how to get the second result by grouping.

Comment: Very unclear. What do all the numbers mean? What exactly do you want?

Comment: I don't get the second grouping, could you explain the syntax? What does `XYZ-->1/2+1/2` mean? You wrote `2/2(no. of occurences of ABC)` so I guess (but that's not clear) that the second number is the number of occurences, but what's the first? What does the number of occurences refer to? Global occurences or per group?

Comment: A better explanation of the 2nd output would help to give you a solution.

Comment: in ABC-->((group1 occurs twice)/(total number of occurences of ABC))+((group3 occurs once)/(total number of occurences of ABC)). so     ABC-->2/3+1/3

Answer (score 1):

You should use a map of collections instead of a plain set. Something like this:

```
Map<String, Map<String,Integer>> supermap = new Hashmap();      
BufferedReader reader = null;        
try {
    reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.csv"));            
    String[] currLineSplitted;            
    while (reader.ready()) {
        currLineSplitted = reader.readLine().split(",");

        Map<String,Integer> innermap;

        if(supermap.contains(currLineSplitted[0]){
            innermap = supermap.get(currLineSplitted[0]);

            if(innermap.contains(currLineSplitted[1]){
                innermap.put(currLineSplitted[1],
                             innermap.get(currLineSplitted[1])++);
            } else {
                innermap.put(currLineSplitted[1],new Integer(1));//EDITED
            }
        } else {
            innermap=new Hashmap();
            innermap.put(currLineSplitted[1],new Integer(1));//EDITED
            supermap.put(currLineSplitted[0], innermap);
        }
    }         
    Collections.sort(supermap.keySet() , new YourOwnComparator() );//EDITED

    for (String userID : supermap.keySet()) {
        Map m = supermap.get(userID);
        //===========first result=============
        for(String group : m.keySet()){
            System.out.println(userID + group + " : " + m.get(group));
        }
        //=====================================
    } 
    for (String userID : supermap.keySet()) {
        Map m = supermap.get(userID);
        //===========second result=============
        int numberOfGroups = m.size();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();             
        sb.append(userID+"-->");

        for(String group : m.keySet()){
            sb.append(m.get(group).toString()+"/"+numberOfGroups);
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
        //=====================================
    } 

} finally {
    if (reader != null) {
        reader.close();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: My bad: the Integers must be created with 1 as start value. The sorting of your entries can be implemented accordingly to [this case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477261/how-to-sort-a-collectiont).

Comment: XYZGroup1 : 0
ABCGroup1 : 0
DEFGroup2 : 0
GHIGroup4 : 0
UVWGroup5 : 0
XYZ-->0/1
ABC-->0/1
DEF-->0/1
GHI-->0/1
UVW-->0/1 this is what i get from the above approach