# To sort the contents of a file using comparator in java

Tags: java, list, file, sorting

I have added the contents of a file through an ArrayList and now I need to sort those contents and then put them back on the file. how can I do it?

```
package training;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Collections;
/* method to create a file, store the contents of list and write read them back
*/

public class FileCreation implements Serializable {
    public void filesPatient(Person p) throws ClassNotFoundException {

        String Filename = "PatientDetails.txt";
        try {
            ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(
                    new FileOutputStream(Filename));
            os.writeObject(p);
            os.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
        System.out.println("Done wRiting");
        try {
            ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(
                    Filename));
            Person l = (Person) is.readObject();
            System.out.println("*****************Patient Details*************");
            System.out.println("Name : " + l.getName() + "\nID: " + l.getId()
                    + "\nGender: " + l.getGender());
            System.out.println();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Please help me find an appropriate method to do it.

Comment: FYI when talking about sorting, it would be more useful to see the code where you manage your ArrayList, than the code where you manage your file I/O

Comment: Do you really want to implement serializable in that class? 
is your question more oriented to how make the file human readable? As @Matt said to sort the contents you have the Collections.sort.

Comment: you should add the code you used in your answer here. But anyway maybe you want to first read all the Persons and add them to the arraylist, and only after you read everything you would do the Collecions.sort(arrlist); and start writing from the order on your array list

Comment: yep..  I m doing it that way..

Answer (score 1):

You could use the Collections.sort method, if you want to sort them by the default String-value sort:

```
Collections.sort( list );
```

Otherwise you can write your own comparator to do your own specific sorting logic. Please check out this post for more examples / explanation:

[How to sort a Collection<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477261/how-to-sort-a-collectiont/2477287#2477287)

EDIT

I believe you are looking for something like this. Note in order to sort an ArrayList, you will have to load the entire list into memory, then sort it, then write the whole list to file, so make sure your list is not too long and will fit in memory.

```
ArrayList<Person> arrlist = new ArrayList<Person>(2);
while(more Person data exists) { // Replace this with however you are loading your data
    p = new Person();
    p.getdata();
    arrlist.add(p);
}

Collections.sort(arrList); // now your list is sorted

for(Person p : arrList) { 
    fc.filesPatient(p);  // add all your patients to file, from your list which is now sorted
}
```

Comment: ArrayList<Person> arrlist = new ArrayList<Person>(2);            p = new Person();
  p.getdata();
  arrlist.add(p);
  fc.filesPatient(p);

  p = new Person();
  p.getdata();
  arrlist.add(p);
  fc.filesPatient(p);

Comment: I have used an arrayList not a HashMap. I dont know how to pass objects to a comparator and in which class should i implement it. pls help..

Comment: Can u explain what is "more" and "data exists".

Comment: I wanna add unsorted objects to a file.. write the unsorted list.. Then perform sorting using comparator and store the sorted order back to the file.

Comment: Where are you loading Person data from?

Comment: Ok so by "more data exists", you have to load objects from a file - so for each object in that file, add it to the list

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<Person> arrlist = new ArrayList<Person>(2);
p = new Person();
p.getdata();
arrlist.add(p);
fc.filesPatient(p);

p = new Person();
p.getdata();
arrlist.add(p);
fc.filesPatient(p);
```