# Trouble trying to invert an array list

Tags: java, arrays, list, collections

I'm trying to invert an arrayList of votes in order to yield preference (i.e. a vote of 2,4,1,3, after inverted is 3,1,4,2. the indexed preference is 3). I believe this can be done with Collections but the list is of difference type (type Vote). Just need some guidance on how i could sort this preference order when i cant use Collections methods on Vote.

```
    public Vote invertVote() {

        VoteList invVote = (VoteList) ((Vote) vote).copyVote();

        Iterator<Integer> iter = invVote.iterator();
            while(iter.hasNext()){
            iter.next();
            Collections.reverse(invVote);

    }


    return invVote;


}
```

Note Vote is a collection of integers representing a single vote. VoteList implements Vote. copyVote() is used to create a deep copy of the vote in order to not alter it and return a new Vote object. Still stuck the error during Collections.reverse(invVote)

Comment: So that means you have an ``ArrayList<Vote>``? Where's the problem using ``Collections.reverse(list)``?

Comment: Sort or reverse? For sorting related questions start with this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2477334/133645

Comment: Trying that gives "the method reverse (list) is not applicable for the arguments (Vote). Trying to ultimately take the list of integers (ArrayList) and return it as type Vote (an inverted version of the arraylist)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this can be done using collection you just need to call the method  [Collections.reverse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse(java.util.List))...

```
public static void reverse(List<?> list)
```

> Reverses the order of the elements in the specified list.
>
> This method
>   runs in linear time.

## Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Random rnd = new Random();
    List<Integer> myInteger = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        myInteger.add(rnd.nextInt(10));
    }
    // the list
    System.out.println(myInteger);
    // the list sorted
    Collections.sort(myInteger);
    System.out.println(myInteger);
    // the list inverted
    Collections.reverse(myInteger);
    System.out.println(myInteger);
}
```

---

in your case use the class Votes instead of integer and make the class to implement the comparable interface where you define the sorting logic....

Comment: You should add that sorting requires that the list's generic is `Comparable` and overrides the `compareTo()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Collections.reverse(list);` [check documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse%28java.util.List%29).

Comment: Yea, you are right, I looked intto different method in class.