# Refactoring the Code using Apache Commons API

Tags: java

please help me i am kinda stuck in this code.. im new to maven/ apache commons..
i have this code working on my program sorting an element of a LinkedHashMap / OrderedMap
I want to refactor this same code to use the Apache Commons API.. what should i use?
Thank You

Here is the code

```
Set<Map.Entry<String, String>> foundSet = MainProgram.cellData.entrySet();
List<Map.Entry<String, String>> foundListEntry = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String, String>>(foundSet);

        Collections.sort(foundListEntry, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, String>>() {
                public int compare(Entry<String, String> es1, Entry<String, String> es2) {
                    return es1.getKey().compareTo(es2.getKey());
                }
        });

        MainProgram.cellData.clear();

        for(Map.Entry<String, String> map : foundListEntry) {
            MainProgram.cellData.put(map.getKey(), map.getValue());
        }

        System.out.println("\nThe table has been Successfuly Sorted!\n");

        updateData();
        menuPrint();
```

Comment: anyone? please help. thnx

Comment: it looks like you want https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/comparator/package-summary.html and https://stackoverflow.com/a/2477281/307743